# A plugin System for react components using webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm developing a micro frontend architecture using module federation in Webpack in order to develop and deploy all parts of my web application separately. Everything sounds great but the problem is all remote modules should be specified explicitly in the Webpack configuration file. I need something like `/plugins` in the root directory of my built project And I want to import All `.js` files in that directory and render all of them in my react project.

Is there a way to implement a plugin system for react components using Webpack? Is there any way at all to achieve this goal?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question entirely. However, it seems you are looking for a way to pull in the remotes based on an external file. If this is the case, you could do this from your webpack file by reading in the external file. For example, say you have yaml files (staging, dev, prod), read these and map them to your remotes.

Comment: The point is, I want to attach them to my project after webpack build like a plugin. So the webpack is ignorant about these plugins. I was surprised that nobody thought about it before.

Comment: This is the closest thing I've came across to your question.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jlEEmiBSvI&list=PLNqp92_EXZBLr7p7hn6IYa1YPNs4yJ1t1&index=8